# type to an element with selenium web driver and java

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

I need to write something into this element:

```
<div class="RichTextEditorWidget ViewBorder com-ibm-team-workitem-shared-RichText cke_editable cke_editable_inline cke_contents_ltr" contenteditable="true" dojoattachpoint="_editorAttachPoint" tabindex="0" spellcheck="true" role="textbox" aria-label="Summary">
TEXT
<br type="_moz"/>
</div>
```

I tried to find this element with xpath and cssSelector but never found the element.
Is anyone know how should I do it??

Comment: It will help if you share the code you have tried.

Comment: this isn't duplicate because I have a specific problem with a specific element, all the other "duplicated" question are referred to another web element and their answers aren't helping.